# Node/Express: Read JSON file from URL with SuperAgent

Tags: node.js, json, express, superagent

So I have a small problem with my app - I need to send a GET request to a PHP back-end that gives me Amazon S3 url to a file that I need to parse and use in some function. 
I'm using SuperAgent createRequest() for that and it works just fine, I get my JSON, when I enter this url to browser I can see that JSON, but I need my app to read this JSON from url, and SuperAgent request doesn't do that. Here is code sample (simplified):

```
async process(projectId: number, token: string): any {
    const projectDocumentUrl = `${this.config.apiUrl}/v1/projects/${projectId}/files/script-document`;
    const projectScriptRequest = createRequest(projectDocumentUrl);
    projectScriptRequest.set('Authorization', token).set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    const source: Document = {};
    let scriptLocation = '';
    await projectScriptRequest.then((response: Response) => {
        console.log(response.body.file.url);
        scriptLocation = response.body.file.url;
    });
    const scriptJsonRequest = await createRequest(scriptLocation);
    await scriptJsonRequest.then((scriptResponse: Response) => {
        console.log(scriptResponse.body);
        source.document = scriptResponse.body.source.document;
    });
}
```

Is there some other way to get JSON from url or am I doing something wrong here? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score -2):

To read an Json URL in NodeJS. You can can use package `node-fetch` to read it. First you need to install `node-fetch` by command `npm install node-fetch`. Then send the request to that URL using `node-fetch`. I believe that it is a GET request. Here is the sample code:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
(async(){
  const url = YOU_URL;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const result = await response.toJson();
})();
```

Comment: the question was for `superagent`, not `node-fetch`